# Exiting Qt application does not kill spawned threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a Qt program that is using the QtConcurrent API to spawn worker threads. The problem I am having is that the worker threads keep going even if I exit the Qt application.

I have an actionExit in my menu, which is what i am using to close the app, or the "X" in the window corner. Is there any way to make these kill off all threads related to this app?

Thanks

Comment: What is your operating system or thread library? Could you show part of your code? If you use `pthread`, I guess your program is not terminated and blocked.

Comment: the OS is Linux. I am assuming QtConcurrent uses pthreads behind the scenes, but not 100% sure

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure that the UI application really closes? You might be missing:

```
qApp->setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(true);
```

Otherwise QT only hides your window. To debug put a breakpoint behind your 
`mainWindow->exec();` and see whether it is really reached.

If you confirm that exec() returns and QTConcurrent really hangs (it might be possible: http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2008-06/thread00414-0.html), then do:

```
exit(0);
```